# How to make button that was created in iOS-Designer public?

Tags: xamarin.ios

Basically I want to be able to access my button, which is located in a custom cell in a table view, in my source class in the GetCell-Method. Unfortunatley iOS-Designer sets the visibility on private.

How do I change this or do I have to create a Button programmatically?

EDIT: I want to access it like this in my source class

```
var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(CellIdentifier) as SearchDetailsCell;
var rownumber = cell.OpenDocumentButton.Tag;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply change the access specifier in designer file

As, I did below;

```
namespace MYPROJ.iOS
{
    [Register ("LargePhotoViewController")]
    partial class LargePhotoViewController
    {
        [Outlet]
        [GeneratedCode ("iOS Designer", "1.0")]
        public UILabel Comment { get; set; }

        [Outlet]
        [GeneratedCode ("iOS Designer", "1.0")]
        UIImageView Image { get; set; }

        void ReleaseDesignerOutlets ()
        {
            if (Comment != null) {
                Comment.Dispose ();
                Comment = null;
            }
            if (Image != null) {
                Image.Dispose ();
                Image = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set a tag to your button (11 in the below example) and then access it like :

```
UIButton MyButton = (UIButton)cell.ViewWithTag (11);
```

Comment: Won't help since I have no access to the button from my source class.